# get type from library assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, mediatr

I want to create a .NET Core REST API with MediatR. My projects are

- API project
- Application project containing the commands, queries and pipeline behaviours

To setup the dependency injection I have to call the

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
```

in the `ConfigureServices` method of the **Startup.cs** (API project). My commands and queries come from a different assembly (Application) so I have to pass in the library assembly instead of Startup. Please see the answer from this post

[Why doesn't Mediatr resolve method when entites are in different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337259/why-doesnt-mediatr-resolve-method-when-entites-are-in-different-projects)

My code should look like

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationAssembly));
```

but I can't just pass in "Application". What needs to get passed in, when commands and queries come from a library project?

---

I solved it by passing in a class from that library

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Application.Queries.GetUsersQuery));
```

I think this is a really bad approach because when this class gets moved or deleted, the API projects needs to get fixed too.

So any better solutions are highly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't be moving or deleting the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you need to pass type information from the assembly, not specific class types.

On the [github project](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) of the extensions you will see this line in the examples

> ..... or with an assembly:
>
> services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Which is what you are looking for i think.
In your case the code will look something like this:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetUsersQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

If you want to be fully independant of the type then you can use something like this

```
services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies());
```

This will scan all assemblies loaded in the app domain.